# Doctrine 2 in ZF2 application: Entities are not being found "No Metadata Classes to process."

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

In a Zend Framework 2 Project, Doctrine 2 is not able to find my Entities and I am not sure why. To me everything looks correct, but the `php ./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:schema-tool:create` command to create the database based on the entities results in `No Metadata Classes to process.`.

Of course I made sure first that all modules are loaded, so it's not that easy ;-) I also already did some research on that problem and it seems that most of the time, it's namespace related, but again, I don't see anything wrong there. I also generated the autoload files.

*Are you able to spot anything wrong in these files, why is Doctrine not able to find the Entities? Could it be related to something else than an error in my files?*

In `module.config.php`, Doctrine is configured like this:

```
'doctrine' => [
    'driver' => [
      'Catalog_entities' => [
        'class' =>'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
        'cache' => 'array',
        'paths' => [__DIR__ . '/../src/Catalog/Entity']
      ],
    ],

    'orm_default' => [
      'drivers' => [
        'Catalog\Entity' => 'Catalog_entities'
      ],
    ],
],
```

`module.config.php` has no `namespace` declaration since it's included into `Module.php` which has `namespace Catalog;` at the top.

The Entity at `module/Catalog/src/Catalog/Entity/WorkEntity.php` looks like this:

```
namespace Catalog\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

    /** @ORM\Entity */
    class Work {
        /**
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
         */
        protected $id;

        public function getId() {
          return $this->id;
        }

        public function setId($id) {
          $this->id = $id;
        }
}
```

Comment: Either your class name should be `WorkEntity` OR that code should be at `module/Catalog/src/Catalog/Entity/Work.php`. Not sure if that's your issue but it can't be helping that the filename doesn't match the class name.

Comment: @Crisp Of course, otherwise the autoloading can't work! Although this didn't fix my issue, I am sure this would have been popped really quick.

Answer (score 1):

First fix @Crisp his comment. File names and class names should always correspond.

If that doesn't solve it you could check if you module.config.php is loaded correctly in your `Module.php` like this:

```
/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getConfig()
{
    return __DIR__ . '/../../config/module.config.php';
}
```

I would also suggest using the namespace constant so you can simply copy your configs to different modules without changing a thing and minimizing the risk of overwriting another config when you forget to change something. So like this:

```
'driver' => [
    __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver' => [
        'class' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\AnnotationDriver',
        'cache' => 'array',
        'paths' => [__DIR__ . '/../src/' . __NAMESPACE__ . '/Entity']
    ],
    'orm_default' => [
        'drivers' => [
            __NAMESPACE__ . '\Entity' => __NAMESPACE__ . '_driver'
        ]
    ]
],
```